# location.href taking considerable time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a ajax call to server. on success i am reloading the page with search result. Code for the same is:

```
function searchData(){
     $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/tool/search",
        data :  "empId=" + $(".empId").val() + "&submit=Search",
        success : function(data) {
          location.href="/tool/search?empId="+ $(".empId").val() +"&submit=Search";
        }
    });
}
```

But, it is taking so much time for reloading the page, while I am receiving the data from server before this [ getting in firebug]. Can any one help on this. On success i have to load the same jsp page from where the request is generated.

Comment: So the problem is that your search servlet is slow?  What does it do?

Comment: fetching some data from DB only, but i am receiving the search result faster from servlet, This is for sure, as in firebug i am getting the response quite earliar

Comment: Any other way to reloading the page with selection other that location.href. I cant use location.reload as i have to retain the selection befor ajax call

Comment: Your search seems rather redundant. You use Ajax to pass specific data to the page and on success you pass the same data to the same page again.
Are you using  a framework on the server side?

Comment: no, its a servlet only, any other way, as to retain selection i cant use location.reload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above jquery ajax is very strange, why do you reload the servlet query after sucessfully performing an ajax query.  The below seems more logical

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/tool/search",
    data :  "empId=" + $(".empId").val() + "&submit=Search",
    success : function(data) {
      // use the data
      // maybe like
      $(".results").html (data);
    }
});
```